# Why "and" and "or" provide these results after receiving lists?

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, racket, sicp

I am using Racket and Dr. Racket for an educational purpose.

After the following definitions of variable "x" and "y":

```
(define x (list 1 2 3))
(define y (list 4 5 6))
```

I decided to create 3 different lists using these variables.

First:

```
(append x y)

>> '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Second:

```
(cons x y)

>> '((1 2 3) 4 5 6)
```

Third:

```
(list x y)

>> ((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

After that, I decided to use the boolean operators "and" and "or" with the three lists. What surprised me was the output. Why does this happen? Why "or" and "and" choose one of the lists? What's the ratio behind this decision?

```
(and (append x y) (cons x y) (list x y))

>> '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))

(or (append x y) (cons x y) (list x y))

>> '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: `and` returns the value of the *last* expression that is *truthy* or `#f` if at least one expression is false, whereas `or` returns the value of the *first* expression that is truthy or `#f` if all are false.

Remember: in Scheme, the only false value is `#f`, whereas anything else is considered true, hence we use the moniker "truthy" - to denote a non-false value. In particular, in your code this:

```
(and (append x y) (cons x y) (list x y))
```

Returns the value of the last truthy expression: `(list x y)`, whereas this:

```
(or (append x y) (cons x y) (list x y))
```

Returns the value of the first truthy expression: `(append x y)`.

Comment: This is the case in most other languages, and it can be used in handy idioms. For example, to divide by a number preventing a zero division you can write: (and (not (= x 0)) (/ 1 x)), it will return 1/x if x is not zero, or nil otherwise.

Comment: It does not return the expressions, but their values.

Answer (score 4):

**`and` and `or` are also control flow operators**

You could think of `and` and `or` of special control flow operators. They not functions. A function `and` would get its arguments evaluated and then might return *true* or *false*.

In this case `and` and `or` are not functions and under some circumstances not every arguments are evaluated:

- `or` immediately returns when it sees a *true* value
- `and` immediately returns when it sees a *false* value

**The return value**

Both also return a *true* value, when there is one:

- `or` returns the first *true* value
- `and` returns the last *true* value, when all arguments are *true*

Since *true* means not only a single boolean value, but most other objects are also *true*, you see that it returns a list in your case. Only `#f` is not *true*.

**Other conditional control flow operators**

Examples would be:

- if
- cond
- case
- when
- unless